# Setting up a 2-node Hadoop cluster on VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, ip, cluster-computing

**I'm unable to open `namenode:50070`, however, `namenode:50030` works fine.**

[image]

I've set up a 2 node cluster on VirtualBox. The host OS is windows 7, and I have 2 guests that are both ubuntu. 1 slave and 1 master.

The master `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.1.124   namenode
192.168.1.125   slave1
```

the master `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback 

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
address 192.168.1.124
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

the slave `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.1.124   namenode
192.168.1.125   slave1
```

the slave `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth3
iface eth3 inet static
address 192.168.1.125
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

**Why can't I open `50070`?**

when I do `netstat -ar`n:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth2
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth2
```

this output shows that my nodes are indeed started. doesnt it?

```
sudo /usr/local/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh 
[sudo] password for hadoop: 
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-namenode-namenode.out
192.168.1.124: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-datanode-namenode.out
192.168.1.125: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-datanode-slave1.out
namenode: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-secondarynamenode-namenode.out
starting jobtracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-jobtracker-namenode.out
192.168.1.125: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-tasktracker-slave1.out
192.168.1.124: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-root-tasktracker-namenode.out
```

Comment: Starting, not started..

Comment: ooh! will it notify me when started?how long does it take to get started?

Comment: Ideally it should not take any time.. Unfortunately you won't see anything on the shell.. JPS, webui, and the logs will help you in verifying whether the process are running or not, JPS being the most convenient option..

Comment: cool! how do i install JPS?

Comment: sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk

Comment: unfortunately im unable to see outside the network for some reason

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Something else is getting installed on your machine right now. Try installing open jdk once it is over. What are you not able to see??

Comment: installed! the output of jps is 3060 Jps

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is some problem with your cluster. Your web console is showing `zero` nodes. Make sure your Hadoop daemons are running fine. Were you able to start them properly? Use `JPS` to check if the daemons are running properly.

Comment: hadoop@namenode:~$ jps
The program 'jps' can be found in the following packages:
 * openjdk-6-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

Comment: I would suggest to have JPS with you.. Comes in pretty handy.

Comment: so i got jps!! what do i do now?

Comment: You need to look into the setup..JPS is showing that nothing is running. Try to dig the logs..

Comment: im really appreciating your help!! could you please advise on exactly which log files you want to see?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33103/discussion-between---and-tariq)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was away for a while. Hadoop logs, inside your HADOOP_HOME/logs folder.

Comment: i've gotten everything to work! although output of jpg is: 8694 Jps ..i actually got 1 master and 3 slaves up and running! i ran a mapreduce job with success! what projects are you working on"?